# ng-src with ng-if condition inside ng-repeat still loads image in the background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have a scope object which contains objects which has 3 different images.I'm displaying the image inside a div which repeats till the length of the scope object.I have 3 different img tags which have ng-if attribute and only one of the 3 images is displayed at a time.But when I check the network section of the chrome's developer tools i found that all the images are requested from the server even though when they are not displayed.How to prevent them from loading ?

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="image in images">
 <img ng-if="zoom == 1" ng-src="{{image.small}} alt="{{image.text}}">
 <img ng-if="zoom == 2" ng-src="{{image.medium}} alt="{{image.text}}">
 <img ng-if="zoom == 3" ng-src="{{image.big}} alt="{{image.text}}">
</div>
```

Shouldn't ng-if prevent the image from loading if the condition is false?
I'm using angularjs 1.5

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your issue. For me, it is loading whenever I request for particular image

Comment: @NagaveerGowda yes you are correct!! even I created a plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/v51IaYClXlTxMwjYcvXJ?p=preview
which is also working fine. But i cant figure out what is causing this in my case.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7926) you need to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` with `ng-src` to prevent loading unneeded images.

Comment: ng-show doesn't work that way.It will load the images

Comment: Did you try it though? I understand the difference between ```ng-if``` (which doesn't append element to the DOM at all) and ````ng-show``` (which is in the DOM but hidden). However, to my knowledge it was intended for ```ng-show``` to prevent loading needed resources form AngularJS >1.2.x.